# How to resolve lifecycle scripts issue?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-run

I explain u all my process to have this error so :

1. I create a folder for my project
2. I open the terminal in the folder and i do the command `npm init`
3. I create index.js file in the folder
4. I do the command `npm install`
5. I do the command `npm run`

When i do the `npm run` command i get this error

```
Lifecycle scripts included in dis_bot1@1.0.0:
  test
    echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1
```

This is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "dis_bot1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: what do you want to do when `npm run` happens?

Comment: You asked that question already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73465538/how-can-i-resolve-lifecycle-scripts-error)

Comment: And again, this is not an error, `npm run` just list all scripts you have declared.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski you stop respond and answer was closed.

The answer i get here is the answer i needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm run` needs an argument to determine which script to run.

i.e. `npm run test` would run the `test` script defined in your package.json file.

Comment: Oooh ok I understand but it was always like that ?

Comment: If you run `npm run` alone, it will list the available scripts which is exactly what you were getting:

```
Lifecycle scripts included in dis_bot1@1.0.0:
  test
    echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1
```

The output above is telling you that, in the lifecycle scripts, there's a `test` script with the content: `echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1`